# Calculating data amount being mined. Server

Tags: blockchain, cpp-ethereum, bitcoin

Does anyone know how to calculate hardware being used by mining activity on a blockchain? I'm curious what the equivalent hardware usage is in a blockchain. I'm looking for a formula of blockchain activity= so much data transfer. Ideally I want to chart it as such.

Etherium blockchain data= data transfer rate
Maintaining blockchain would require= server info = amount of servers, cpu's, ram
Computing would require= (#AMD Cards by a type), (#Nvidia cards by a type)

I thought it would be a neat factoid for Bitcoin, Eth, Zcash. Litecoin with similar info.

On top of that how much data all block chains are using would be fun. It would be an interesting reference to the scope and volume of cryptocurrency world wide and I would be interested in seeing a reference like that somewhere.